# Flickering seams when scaling tiled images in Safari on the Mac

Tags: macos, css, safari, css-transitions

I'm trying to scale a bunch of tiled images in Safari. Safari on iOS displays this correctly. However, on the Mac, there is some weird flickering visible between the images while they are scaling. Once the animation stops, transparent lines are also visible between the tiles.

I've made a Pen showing the behaviour: http://cdpn.io/gdcxD

I've read a bunch of stuff suggesting that I use `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` or some other esoteric webkit directive. I've tried a couple of those, but they do not make any difference.

Ultimately, this will be used in a iBooks Author widget, so it needs to work both on iOS and on the Mac.

I do not really care how this gets solved except for one thing: I need to keep the `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` on the images so they display correctly on iOS.

Any ideas ?

**Edit**: The iBooks Author Widget I'm making will allow the user to zoom in on the tiled image. The images I'm using are large (1500 x 1200 px), but I'm scaling them down on the page to show the whole tiled image. I need to preserve their quality so the user can zoom in on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to the browser using native system graphic processing such as anti-aliasing when scaling images. On the Mac it seems as images are not anti-aliased correctly at the edges which will at some sizes leave transparent (anti-aliased) pixels at the edges.

One way to solve this is to use a canvas element instead which you draw all your tiles to, then transform the canvas element instead.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    tileW = 100,
    tileH = 100,
    cols = 10,
    rows = 10,
    x, y;

canvas.width = tileW * cols;
canvas.height = tileH * rows;

for(y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < cols; y++) {
         /// use spritesheet of image array here... just for example
         ctx.drawImage(spriteSheet, srcX, srcY, tileW, tileH,  // use position for x/y in spritesheet here instead (or 0,0 if image array)
                                    x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH);
    }
}

parentElement.appendChild(canavas);
```

Now apply the CSS to the canvas element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! The flickering is indeed gone when I insert all the images in a canvas. However, when scaling the canvas, I lose the quality of the images. Any ideas on how I could preserve the image quality when scaling the whole thing ? (I updated my question to describe why I'm scaling the images)

Comment: @agregoire ah.. you will probably have to go a bit deeper on the concept introducing for example sort of mipmapping for the tile images. You can always redraw everything using canvas alone so that canvas becomes a static viewport for the tiles instead. The performance is good. You can redraw the tiles with scaled position and destination size. This will interpolate the images as with transforms.

Comment: That's the solution I ended up going with. I'm implementing the zoom myself within a canvas element. There are still some rough edges, but I'm getting there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using position:relative; on the img element.

Comment: Unfortunately, the flickering is still present after adding `position: relative`.